# Awesomium web browser doesn't show the page

Tags: winforms, awesomium

I have made a form which takes a few URLs in the constructor and loads them into some awesomuim web controls on the form.
It worked fine in the first computer but when I move the program to another computer (with the code), it doesn't show the page in the control. when I move the mouse over the control, it shows the busy icon.
But, if i put a breakpoint somewhere in the constructor and then click continue in visual studio, it works fine! I tried to put a sleep in the constructor but it didn't do the job.

here's the code :

```
 public BrowsersWindow(List<string> links)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
  //      Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Links = links;
        Browsers = groupBox1.Controls;  
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (index < Links.Count && index < Browsers.Count)
        {
            Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl current = 
        (Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl)Browsers[index];
            try
            {
                current.Source = new Uri(Links[index]);
            }
            catch { }

            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you say "move the program to another computer" - you mean native or virtual machine? if vm, check out how many processor cores have you set up. It happens to be the reason of many Awesomium problems

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30604057/4945059