# Awesomium Winforms does not work in VMWare

Tags: c#, debugging, awesomium

We have an application that runs Awesomium 1.7.5.1 great on our physical machines but will fail on virtual machines.  The one "gotcha" is running on a virtual machine with a remote debugger attached seems to somehow make Awesomium work.

Comment: How many processor cores did you set in vm settings?

Comment: One.  I just tried switching to 4 in my VM and it works great all of the sudden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup at least 2 processor cores in your vm when using Awesomium